# Calculate the field of view of a camera (draw a pyramid) get 4 edge vectors

Tags: analytic-geometry, projection

I would like to draw a pyramid (representing the boundries of the camera).
The input parameters are:

- Camera position Pc
- Camera direction Vc
- Camera up direction Vupc
- Camera horizontal viewing angle Alpha
- Either aspect ratio of the view of camera (horizontal and vertical
  sides) or vertical viewing angle
- Side length of the pyramid: A (if we have the 4 edge vectors of the
  pyramid, we can determine the 4 points which are in the directions of
  the vectors from Pc in the distance of A)

Thank you for your help!